# Strict Standards: Declaration of GalleryTablealbum::_getAssetParentId() should be compatible with JTable

Tags: javascript, php, json, joomla

I'm newbie  in scripting especially in PHP or Java, could you help me to figure out the issue of this error ? 
Thank you in advance.

> Strict Standards: Declaration of
>   GalleryTablealbum::_getAssetParentId() should be compatible with
>   JTable::_getAssetParentId(JTable $table = NULL, $id = NULL) in
>   /administrator/components/com_gallery/tables/album.php on line 71

Also I switched from PHP 5.x to PHP 7. And getting error :( 
Fatal error: Cannot use Joomla\String\String as String because 'String' is a special class name in

> libraries/vendor/jooml‌​a/registry/src/Forma‌​t/Json.php on line 12

Any help ? please :((

Comment: As for the first one: The function `_getAssetParentId()` inside the class GalleryTablealbum seems to not accept any arguments (or not the right ones) like the function of the same name inside the parent class of GalleryTablealbum which is named JTable does. 
If that's your code, have a look at the parent class and copy over the arguments to your children class (and when you call the parent at the end of the function add those parameters too).

Comment: If its a joomla core (e.g.) its propably not worth your time to change that because there will be a huge amount of other problems after you fixed this one. Check that your joomla version runs on php7. If not I'd rather update your joomla core.

Comment: @Hafenkranich 
Thank you for your answer. Yes, you're right, that's joomla core issue. I didn't upgrade it yet, but I'll do it today. And  inform the result. :)